# how to stop Kile (the editor) from automatically adding quote mark?

Tags: kile, auto-completion

I'm on Debian 7.3 KDE desktop with Kile v. 2.1.0, the editor for LaTeX. I installed it from the repos without the LaTeX-related recommended packages, after 'manually' installing TeXLive from a CTAN mirror. 
I'm still getting used to Kile's way of working but I want it to stop automatically adding another quote mark after I type this character:`'`, thus making it look like a double quote:`"`. I tried to turn it off by going to Settings > Configure Kile > General > un-tick "Automatically insert opening & closing double quotes for LaTeX". I actually like this feature when I need to open and close double quotes for dialogues (``` He said:``Let's get a drink!" ```) but it's working against me, now. How do I correct it? Is there a file somewhere (`~/.config/kile...` maybe?) that I have to touch up?

EDIT: I've added a picture below. Do you people have the same view of Configure Kile > Complete ? I think I have a bugged version of Kile. 
[image]

Comment: I don't know how to switch it off but I can tell you that you can safely re-enable "Automatically insert opening and closing double quotes for LaTeX". It really only takes care of double quotes. I have it enabled and my Kile does not show the behaviour you describe. Did you look for a weird extension that might be doing this?

Comment: I don't see this behaviour with Kile 2.1.3.

Comment: I don't see this behavior with Kile 2.1.0, actually. (I'm on Kubuntu but I wouldn't think that would matter.) So it must be something in the configuration, or an extension, or something like that.

Comment: In Configure Kile > Extensions I have this list of plugins: AutoBrace [], Data Tools [], Exporter [x], Highlight selection[x], IconInserter[], Insane (not ZEN) HTML coding[], Insert File[]. Only 2 of them are selected (hence the [x]). What could it be?

Comment: Anyone has my same view of `Configure Kile > Complete`? See picture above...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user **cfr** for suggesting this work-around (see discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159277/add-non-english-spell-checker-and-or-dictionary-to-kile?noredirect=1#comment363930_159277))!

To solve the double quote effect of `'` mark, go to Settings menu > Configure Kile > Editor > Editing > Auto-Brace plugin. Select it and click on its configuration button, on the right. Un-check the option "Automatically add closing quotation marks". A msg box will pop-up telling you *The autobrace plugin supersedes the Kate-internal AutoBrackets feature. The setting was automatically disabled for this document*. This solved the problem of Kile automatically adding an extra `'` mark every time I wanted to type `I'm` or `it's`, however now it DOESN'T automatically close brackets as it used to. This is a problem since I often need nested brackets in math environments. Maybe I'll have to un-check the other check-box too, in the configuration dialogue box of the AutoBrace plugin...